# "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters" in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am receiving this error "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." I got this error when I search for email rest of things working perfectly.

I also changed these two things but no luck

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = True;

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=';
```

Comment: show the url and how the url is generated

Comment: Note that "I have googled" is generally not thought of as sufficient evidence of research. Readers will be glad to hear you've used a search engine, but some notes what research that tried or the code you think might help can be very useful. Ultimately, brief questions don't do so well here. [Read this very good advice](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) - it even mentions the "I have googled" phenomenon `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

just change to:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-@\=+()';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = True;
```

to

```
 $config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

hope this will help you.
still getting error ..please post your url and how it generated.